# DoEvent() Returns 0 BUT Run-time Error 2585 This action can't be carried out while processing a form or report event

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

This code was running without a hitch, but now getting Error 2585.

I have looked at [Gustav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472958/1422252) and [Gord Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16724149/1422252) but unless I am missing something (quite possible!) the first does not work and the second seems inapplicable. I saw on another site a suggestion that there might be a duplicate record ID, but I check for that possibility.

I put a call to DoEvent() in response to this error but it returns zero. I also wait for 10 seconds to let other processes run. Still receive the error.

```
Private Sub SaveData_Click()
  Dim myForm As Form
  Dim myTextBox As TextBox
  Dim myDate As Date
  Dim myResponse As Integer

If IsNull(Forms!Ecoli_Data!DateCollected.Value) Then

  myReponse = myResponse = MsgBox("You have not entered all the required data. You may quit data entry by hitting 'Cancel'", vbOKOnly, "No Sample Date")
  Forms!Ecoli_Data.SetFocus
  Forms!Ecoli_Data!Collected_By.SetFocus
  GoTo endOfSub
End If

If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False

myDate = Me.DateCollected.Value

Dim yearAsString As String, monthAsString As String, dayAsString As String, clientInitial As String

Dim reportNumberText As String

reportNumberText = Me!SampleNumber.Value
Debug.Print "reportNumberText = " & reportNumberText

Debug.Print "CollectedBy Index: " & Me!Collected_By & " Employee Name: " & DLookup("CollectedBy", "Data_Lookup", Me.Collected_By)


Dim whereString As String
whereString = "SampleNumber=" & "'" & reportNumberText & "'"
Debug.Print whereString
On Error GoTo errorHandling
DoCmd.OpenReport "ECOLI_Laboratory_Report", acViewPreview, , whereString
DoCmd.PrintOut
DoCmd.Close acReport, "ECOLI_Laboratory_Report", acSaveNo

Dim eventsOpen As Integer
eventsOpen = DoEvents()
Debug.Print "Number of Open Events = " & DoEvents()

    Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime

        PauseTime = 10    ' Set duration.
        Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
        Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
            DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
        Loop
        Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
        TotalTime = Finish - Start  ' Calculate total time.
    myResponse = MsgBox("Processing Report Took " & TotalTime & " seconds.", vbOKOnly)


myResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to add more data?", vbYesNo, "What Next?")


If myResponse = vbYes Then

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "ECOLI_Data", acSaveYes
```

**Error Generated By Line Above** and occurs whether response Y or N to MsgBox.

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ECOLI_Data", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Else
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "ECOLI_Data", acSaveYes

End If
Exit Sub

 errorHandling:
 If Err.Number = 2501 Then
   myResponse = MsgBox("Printing Job Cancelled", vbOkayOnly, "Report Not Printed")
ElseIf Err.Number = 0 Then
   'Do nothing
Else
   Debug.Print "Error Number: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

   myResponse = MsgBox("An Error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error #" & Err.Number)
End If


If Application.CurrentProject.AllForms("ECOLI_Data").IsLoaded Then DoCmd.Close acForm, "ECOLI_Data", acSaveNo

If Application.CurrentProject.AllReports("ECOLI_Laboratory_Report").IsLoaded     Then DoCmd.Close acReport, "ECOLI_Laboratory_Report", acSaveNo

endOfSub:
End Sub
```

Any idea on what am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: The DLookup() looks incomplete to me. What criteria do you want the DLookup to search on? Although doesn't appear to be cause of error, it does not look like a valid expression. acSaveYes has nothing to do with saving data, it is about saving design changes. try acSaveNo.

Comment: Also, probably need to close the form after opening other form. Recommend you put the GoToRecord code behind the opened form.

Comment: The form you're closing, is that the form you're running this code on? Why are you closing and then reopening a form?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, Yes. I closed the form and re-opened it because I could not figure out how to completely clear the form for new records. As I think about it there must be an iterative way to move through form fields and clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem, but the following might help:

I assume you run into troubles because you're closing and opening the form in the same operation. To avoid doing this, you can open up a second copy of the form, and close the form once the second copy is open. This avoids that issue.

To open a second copy of the form:

```
Public Myself As Form

Public Sub CopyMe()
    Dim myCopy As New Form_CopyForm
    myCopy.Visible = True
    Set myCopy.Myself = myCopy
End Sub
```

(CopyForm is the form name)

To close a form that may or may not be a form created by this function

```
Public Sub CloseMe()
    If Myself Is Nothing Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Else
        Set Myself = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

More information on having multiple variants of the same form open can be found [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html), but my approach differs from the approach suggested here, and doesn't require a second object to hold references and manage copies.

Comment: Erik, your suggestion was not quite correct but enabled me to find the error. The last Field in my form had a LostFocus() Procedure that called SaveData() -  the procedure above - thereby creating an Open Event when I tried to close the form. 
.
I changed it to an AfterUpdate() and problem solved! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
`DoCmd.Close acForm, "ECOLI_Data", acSaveYes`
```

doesn't save the record you are on, it just saves any changes to the form design.

You should probably use

```
If Me.Dirty Then Me.dirty = False
```

to force a save of the current record if any data has changed.