# Open multiple forms issue in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got query to make some modification that enable user to open multiple instances of the form when they do search data. I got manage to create a new module following Allen Browne guide and now I can open multiple instances of the spreadsheet which is good step forward but I cannot find solution how I can open that specific form.

In module I have got following code:

```
Public clnClient As New Collection    'Instances of frmClient.
Function OpenAClient()
    'Purpose:    Open an independent instance of form frmClient.
    Dim frm As Form

    'Open a new instance, show it, and set a caption.
    Set frm = New Form_SurgeriesForm
    frm.Visible = True
    frm.Caption = frm.Hwnd & ", opened " & Now()

    'Append it to our collection.
    clnClient.Add Item:=frm, Key:=CStr(frm.Hwnd)


    Set frm = Nothing
End Function
```

And under my button I replaced bit:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "SurgeriesForm", acNormal
Forms!SurgeriesForm.Requery
```

.. and usef following code:

```
ModuleInstances.OpenAClient
```

I recon I need to add / change somehow the code below to be able to open multiple instances but do not have idea how to do it.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "SurgeriesForm", acNormal
Forms!SurgeriesForm.Requery
```

I appreciate for any help with this as i got stuck and do not know how I can achieve this.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Could you add a link to Allen Brownes guide?  All I can think at the moment is that `DoCmd.OpenForm "SurgeriesForm", acNormal` is opening a new instance of the form which isn't added to the `clnClient` collection so you're having problems referencing that instance?

Comment: Backing up a bit: **Why** do you need to have multiple instances of the same form open at the same time?

Comment: @ashleedawg Could be to view multiple client details at the same time, or maybe invoices... lots of reasons to reuse the same form.  Of course, plenty of times you wouldn't need to use more than one instance of a form so definitely a valid question.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook -- yeah understood, but I get the impression that it may not be necessary in this case.  (A possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/370758)?)

Comment: There are many cases where multiple forms are handy, and many ways to go about it. Allen Browne's tutorial is pretty handy (found [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html)), but a bit long for some use cases. My approach is a little different, and shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679932/7296893)

Comment: Your code should work and open new form everybtime u call openaClient. Make Sure your form auto resize & show in centre desktop property activated. ( can't remember exact property). So your form is not outside of your screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?...

With the button on your `SurgeriesForm` add this code to the `On Click` event to open a new instance of the form:

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()
    OpenAClient
End Sub
```

This will create a new instance of the form each time you click the button.

Next, add a blank combo-box to the form and change it's `Row Source Type` to `Value List`.
Add this code to the form:

```
Private Sub Combo9_GotFocus()
    Dim frm As Variant

    Combo9.RowSource = ""

    For Each frm In clnClient
        Combo9.AddItem frm.Caption
    Next frm
End Sub
```

Now, when you click the drop-down it will list each form that you have created an instance of.

Finally, add this code to the form:

```
Private Sub Combo9_AfterUpdate()
    clnClient(Combo9.Value).SetFocus
End Sub
```

Now, selecting a form name from the combo-box will move the focus to that form.

**NB:**  You'll need to update the name of the controls to match yours.
**NB2:** Remember to open the first form using `OpenAClient` or it won't get listed in the combobox (as it's not in the collection).

Comment: Hi Darren,than you for your quick response. I think I follow your approach and I am doing everything right. I am not getting an error but I cannot see the names listed in the combo box. I can open only single instances of the form. I am suing this code "Private Sub ComboSurgeryForm_GotFocus()
 Dim frm As Variant
    
    For Each frm In clnClient
        ComboSurgeryForm.AddItem frm.Caption
    Next frm
End Sub"

Comment: Not sure.  You have the `OpenAClient()` procedure in a normal module with `Public clnClient As New Collection` at the top before any procedures, event procedure names and control names match correctly.  `Combo-box Row Source Type` is set to `Value List`.  Not sure what effect _suing_ your code will have as it doesn't have legal representation, but worth a try.  I've also updated `Private Sub Combo9_GotFocus()` so it doesn't keep adding to the list everytime you click the control.